# Кнопки назад и вперед в history api

Tags: javascript, html5-history-api

Для перехода назад/вперед использую код

```
addEventListener("popstate",function(e){
    go(location.pathname+location.search);//ajax
},false);
```

но перейти назад можно только один раз, а кнопка вперед недоступна.
Как сделать нормальный функционал?

Answer (score 1):

```
window.history.go(n)
```

где n может быть ( -бесконечность: +бесконечность )